# If I play an action card and it is sabotaged, can I take another action?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

If I play an action card as an action and another player plays sabotage on it, can I take another action or is my action considered taken already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the FAQ here:
http://new.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Twilight%20Imperium%203/ti3faq2-2-4.pdf

> Q: Is an Action Card that has been sabotaged considered played?
>
> A:
> No. For example, a “play as an action” Action Card that is  sabotaged
> does not use up its owner’s action.

So yes, you should be able to play another action.